# Large byte array allocation task manager

Tags: c#, memory

Just for curiosity, I made a small console application as the following code :

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[Int32.MaxValue / 4]; // about 536870911
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

When I run it and it goes to `Console.ReadLine()` I check the task manager. It shows me that my application is only using 2508KB of memory. **How could it be** ?

Comment: Try writing ones to the entire entire array. I suspect it's the same lazy allocation thing that affects native programs.

Comment: The variable is never used.  The compiler is entirely within it's rights to remove all of the code for that allocation entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my results:

In debug mode:

[image]

In release mode:

[image]

Yellow is private bytes, red is working set. In release mode, since nothing uses your variable, it gets optimized away by the compiler.